# Room database : How set default Value from strings resources

Tags: java, android, android-room

How can I set the default value of some fields from resources like strings . because I want set value for different languages

```
@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "") // R.string.someword
private String publisher;
```

When trying to :

```
@ColumnInfo(defaultValue = Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.someword)) 
private String publisher;
```

Get the following error

```
Attribute value must be constant
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short you cannot as such values can change at run time, whilst Room builds the SQL that creates the tables, indexes and views at compile time.

The default = "" parameter is used to apply the value to the `DEFAULT` construct of the `CREATE TABLE ....` sql.

If you successfully compile you can see the generated SQL it's in the java generated (Android View) in the file that is the same name as the @Database class but suffixed with _Impl.